# HTML Loop with If Statement

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using Ionic2/Angular2. I have a collection of `messages` which I loop through and display their details.

```html
<div *ngFor="let message of messages" class="message-wrapper">
  <div *ngIf="!exists(message)">
    <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
      <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
    </div>
    <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
      <div class="message-content">server:{{message.content}}</div>
      <span class="time-tick">
    <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
      <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
        <span class="checkmark">
          <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
          <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </span>
      </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am using an if statement (`<div *ngIf="!exists(message)">`) to decide whether to display the `message` row.

My problem is, even though I have the if statement, and it only displays the correct rows, the non displayed `messages` are still taking up scroll space.  What I mean by that is that there are blank spaces where the non displayed `messages` would be.

[image]

As you can see here, there is some empty space after the last message.

**Question**

Can I structure this `html` so that if the row is filtered, it does not not take up any space?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a runnable example using jFiddle or Stack Overflow's javascript tool or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in a [`template` tag](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!#syntax) holding the loop. Templates won't get rendered so you can put them anywhere you need rendering logic with `ngFor` and `ngIf` at the same time.

```html
<template ngFor let-message [ngForOf]="messages">
    <div *ngIf="!exists(message)" class="message-wrapper">
        <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
            <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
        </div>
        <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
            <div class="message-content">server:{{message.content}}</div>
            <span class="time-tick">
                <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
                <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
                    <span class="checkmark">
                        <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
                        <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Glad, I could help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an html/css issue. Check the css for the "message-wrapper" class. Maybe move that class inside the ng-if statement, and leave the loop on a div with no class.

Comment: Thanks @mavrick9009. I am going with rinukkusu's solution, because I think it's better if there is less in the DOM.